# Comma before independent clause of imperative sentence

Tags: punctuation, subordinate-clauses, imperative-sentences

> It is considered good style to place a comma before *or* when it begins an independent clause. An independent clause is a clause which could stand alone as its own sentence, because it has its own subject and verb.
>
> **Correct:** Didi may want to spend her roulette winnings on that Ferrari she always wanted, or she may go on a luxury vacation.
>
> **Correct:** Didi may want to spend her roulette winnings on that Ferrari she always wanted or a luxury vacation.
>
> **Wrong:** Didi may want to spend her roulette winnings on that Ferrari she always wanted, or a luxury vacation.
>
> https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-or/

Is "or replace the assigned value with another" is an independent clause in this example? Is it correct to put a comma before *or* here?

> To assign a value later, or replace the assigned value with another, use [...]

Or maybe the comma should be removed, and the valid sentence to use it is

> To assign a value later, or **to** replace the assigned value with another, use [...]

Comment: I don't see any imperatives here.

Comment: Putting a comma in the third version doesn't seem a very heinous grammatical sin to me.

Comment: It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to preface the "alternative" clause with a comma before ***or***. Just as in the *spoken* version, the speaker might ***choose to pause*** at that point *[**comma / pause**]* or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is probably not a problem for native speakers, but I always prefer strict rules in writing. In Russian, there are very few choices where you can use punctuation freely. If there is some "definitve" style guide for English that will give "the most correct" way to use punctuation, I would be glad to know.

Comment: I don't think my advice linking the comma to the spoken pause is peculiar to English. Regardless of whether some other language features exactly the same syntax as English *[clause A] **or** [clause B]*, I'm sure ***all*** spoken languages include the possibility of introducing pauses to help the audience parse the syntax of an utterance. Therefore the advice about using the comma (in writing, which is effectively "artificial" language) to reflect a "parsing assistance" pause in speech (***real*** language) should always be helpful. But ***there is no "strict rule" here***. (Sorry! :)

Comment: You should also note that the general trend over many decades now is to *use less punctuation overall*. So much of what you'll find in older style guides (or indeed, older texts in general) will be "old-fashioned". Look at the way modern writers in reputable newspapers use commas, and I'm sure you'll soon agree that today's Guardian writer, for example, will be using a *lot* less commas than, say, Charles Dickens ever did.

Comment: Note that the fact your "alternative" is presented as an ***independent clause*** (potentially valid as a standalone sentence) has no direct relevance to the matter of whether you "should" set it off with a comma. It's really neither here nor there that the *actual* example features *[or] **she may go on a luxury vacation***, as opposed to "deleting" the predictably repeated elements to leave just *[or] [go] **on a luxury vacation***. Also note that even in your example, you've already deleted predictably repeated ***want to spend her roulette winnings***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _"has no direct relevance to the matter of whether you 'should' set it off with a comma"_ - So it seems you don't agree with the Grammarly article here?

Comment: @jsv: I haven't specifically looked at *any* supposed "authority" claiming that whether or not whatever follows ***or*** could be called an "independent clause" makes a difference as to whether or not you should use a comma. But I completely disagree with that concept, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What my English teachers have always said about independent clauses is they have to make sense on their own. Does "or replace the assigned value with another" make sense on its own? (no) Therefore, it is not the independant clause.

However the comma structure is still correct, you can think of it like an interjection or unnecessary information. For example, "I walked down Downing street, or Blonde street for all I care, to get to the prime minister's office". If you removed what's in the commas it should still make sense.

By the way, for the Didi sentence it should be; "Didi may want to spend her roulette winnings on that Ferrari she always wanted or ON a luxury vacation." It is not correct without the "on".

Comment: Isn't it that repeating words such as "on" or, for example, "from" is optional?

Comment: What @jsv  said. The "deletion" of "predictably repeated" ***on*** before ***a luxury vacation*** is entirely an optional stylistic choice. It's misleading for this answer to claim the text *is not correct without the "on".*

Comment: I'm afraid you're a bit confused as regards the use of **or** as a conjunction. It can connect two independent clauses. It's just a connector which doesn't belong to the second clause, and consequently the second clause **makes sense**.